# How do I get Keras predictions to be one hot encoded?

Tags: python, keras, scale, perceptron

hi i write these code and it's totally fine but don't know how to reverse ypred to compare with ytest

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn import datasets

from keras.utils import to_categorical


data=datasets.load_iris()

x=data.data
y=to_categorical(data.target)

xtrain, xtest, ytrain, ytest=train_test_split(x, y,test_size=1/3)

sc=StandardScaler()
xtrain=sc.fit_transform(xtrain)
xtest=sc.transform(xtest)

ann_model=Sequential()

ann_model.add(Dense(units=4,activation='relu', kernel_initializer='uniform', input_dim=4))
ann_model.add(Dense(units=4, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='uniform'))
ann_model.add(Dense(units=3, activation='softmax', kernel_initializer='uniform'))

ann_model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

ann_model.fit(xtrain, ytrain,batch_size=8,epochs=800)

ypred=ann_model.predict(xtest)
```

after this i get a standardized ypred like this:

```
   [9.9993205e-01, 6.7994297e-05, 1.4203579e-19],
   [5.3556296e-12, 4.2303108e-02, 9.5769691e-01],
   [3.1650116e-04, 9.9964631e-01, 3.7194797e-05],
   [1.4751430e-05, 9.9975187e-01, 2.3338773e-04],
   [9.9994361e-01, 5.6439614e-05, 6.4687055e-20],
   [2.6651847e-04, 9.9968839e-01, 4.5110301e-05],
   [1.6542191e-06, 9.9968910e-01, 3.0929857e-04],
   [9.9991632e-01, 8.3733095e-05, 3.4217699e-19],
   [5.8562500e-07, 9.9891603e-01, 1.0833564e-03],
   [2.7507697e-06, 9.9960250e-01, 3.9476002e-04],
   [9.9997449e-01, 2.5457492e-05, 2.2423828e-21],
   [7.1067189e-14, 5.0079697e-03, 9.9499208e-01],
```

but i want my ypred be ones and zeros like ytest:

```
 [0., 1., 0.],
   [0., 0., 1.],
   [1., 0., 0.],
   [0., 0., 1.],
   [0., 1., 0.],
   [1., 0., 0.],
   [0., 0., 1.],
   [0., 0., 1.],
   [0., 0., 1.],
```

how can i reverse my ypred thank you for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `np.argmax` and `keras.utils.to_categorical`:

```
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical

arr = np.array([[9.9993205e-01, 6.7994297e-05, 1.4203579e-19],
   [5.3556296e-12, 4.2303108e-02, 9.5769691e-01],
   [3.1650116e-04, 9.9964631e-01, 3.7194797e-05],
   [1.4751430e-05, 9.9975187e-01, 2.3338773e-04],
   [9.9994361e-01, 5.6439614e-05, 6.4687055e-20],
   [2.6651847e-04, 9.9968839e-01, 4.5110301e-05],
   [1.6542191e-06, 9.9968910e-01, 3.0929857e-04],
   [9.9991632e-01, 8.3733095e-05, 3.4217699e-19],
   [5.8562500e-07, 9.9891603e-01, 1.0833564e-03],
   [2.7507697e-06, 9.9960250e-01, 3.9476002e-04],
   [9.9997449e-01, 2.5457492e-05, 2.2423828e-21],
   [7.1067189e-14, 5.0079697e-03, 9.9499208e-01]])
```

```
new_array = to_categorical(np.argmax(arr, axis=1), 3)
```

`np.argmax` will return the the index where the value is highest (0, 1, or 2), and `to_categorical` will one-hot this new array, so there is a 1 where the prediction was highest. Result:

```
array([[1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1.],
       [0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0.],
       [1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0.],
       [1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0.],
       [1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1.]], dtype=float32)
```

To skip one step, you can also use

```
ypred=ann_model.predict_classes(xtest)
```

which will predict 0, 1 or 2, and then you will just have to do the last step that I suggested:

```
new_array = to_categorical(y_pred, 3)
```

Although full disclosure, I haven't tried the last solution (I don't have a working example).